# Query @xml variable to get a rowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an xml data that looks like below.

```
DECLARE @XmlContent XML
SET @XmlContent = 
'<Entities>
<Entity type = "5">
      <item id ="1"/>
      <item id ="2"/>
      <item id ="2"/>
</Entity>
<Entity type = "6">
      <item id ="3"/>
      <item id ="4"/>
      <item id ="5"/>
</Entity>
</Entities>'
```

I want to select data from this and insert into a table in the following format -

```
------------
Type Id
------------
5     1
5     2
5     2
6     3
6     4
6     5
```

Can some one help me to write query for this in sql server?

Answer (score 6):

```sql
select
  ent.value('@type', 'int') as Type,
  row.value('@id', 'int') as ID
from
  @XmlContent.nodes('/Entities/Entity') foo(ent)
  cross apply ent.nodes('item') bar(row)
```