# How to reduce cost of parsing small XML in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have following T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @DesiredCategories TABLE(CategoryID INT, Search BIT, SearchText NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @DesiredCategories 
    SELECT X.Col.query('id').value('.', 'INT') as CategoryID,
        X.Col.value('@search', 'BIT') as Search,
        X.Col.query('text').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') as SearchText
        FROM .nodes('root/node') X(Col);
```

`@XMLCategoryIDs` contains XML like this:

```
<root>
    <node search="0"><id>10088</id><text></text></node>
    <node search="0"><id>10087</id><text></text></node>
    <node search="0"><id>10090</id><text></text></node>
</root>
```

Sadly, this code have very high subtree cost (for following code snippet it's ~900) and seems to be a perfomance bottleneck.

Execution plan is included - http://pastebin.com/ptnqJ4jX

We are using XML to send varying number of parameters (1-5) to stored procedure.

And yes, I'm total beginner with XML manipulation in SQL.

Comment: See if [cross apply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6304347/11683) or [other things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6305542/11683) work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is stored in a table, you can create a primary xml index to reduce subtree cost for queries against that xml at a later time. You're basically shifting the workload to earlier in the process, but this might help your situation.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Table;
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,DocumentId INT
    ,Xml XML
)

CREATE PRIMARY XML INDEX PXML_Table_Xml
    ON #Table (Xml);
GO

INSERT INTO #Table 
(
    DocumentId
    ,Xml
)
VALUES
(
    1
    ,
    '
    <root>
        <node search="0"><id>10088</id><text></text></node>
        <node search="0"><id>10087</id><text></text></node>
        <node search="0"><id>10090</id><text></text></node>
    </root>
    '
)

DECLARE @DesiredCategories TABLE(DocumentId INT,CategoryID INT, Search BIT, SearchText NVARCHAR(50));



INSERT INTO @DesiredCategories 
    SELECT 
        DocumentId
        ,CategoryID
        ,Search
        ,SearchText
        FROM #Table
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT 
                X.Col.query('id').value('.', 'INT') as CategoryID,
                X.Col.value('@search', 'BIT') as Search,
                X.Col.query('text').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') as SearchText
             FROM Xml.nodes('root/node') X(Col)
        ) A

SELECT * FROM @DesiredCategories
```